# how to find in in which course no trainee enrolled in Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables

The first table `tbl_course`, has columns `id` and `course_name`,

and the second table has columns `id`,`course_id` and `student id`.

How can I find out the course names in which no trainee enrolled?

Comment: Your problem isn't understood properly. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Clarify your question, like `table names` should be clear, and column names should also. Why `course_name` in the first table? I think your database design is bad.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: table one has name tbl_course which contain                             course_id | course_name and the second table has name tbl_enrollement, in this table, i am storing the data who enrolled into the particular course and columns name of "tbl_enrollment" are id, course_id,student_id , now i want to check by mysql Iin which course no trainee enrolled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you all course IDs that have some students enrolled:

```
select course_id from OTHER_TABLE
```

Now, we will use that to filter out these courses from frist table:

```
select * from tbl_course
where id not in (select course_id from OTHER_TABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have two tables. The first table contains list of courses, and the second table holds list of students' ID associated with the course they are enrolled with. So you want to get `course names` that no student enrolled in. I hope the following code will help you:

```
select `course_name` from `tbl_course` where `course_id` not in (select `course_id` from `tbl_enrollement`)
```